# Raspberry Pi | Data Communication | Process Data

Tags: gpio, networking, pi-4, connection, data-transfer

I need to receive electricity data from a charge controller with a raspberry pi and process these data on the hmi screen. How can I get accurate information about raspberry pi data communication, how to use received data. I really need advice.
For example, the controller device supplies a certain electricity to a place. I want to show the size of this electricity on the hmi screen. Device will calculate to electricity degree, i need the show electricity degree on the hmi.
What do I need to learn to do these procedures, how do I progress, I'm really new to this business and the company I work for asked me to deal with this kind of project. maybe I asked something that shouldn't be asked, but even though I'm new, I came across this kind of thing. I feel stuck.

Comment: There are plenty of Pi tutorials.  Search on-line.  Work through ones which interest you.  If you have a problem ask a question.

Comment: @joan While doing research, I wanted to get an idea about how to proceed. I know how to do research, but I felt the need to write here and get ideas because they do these things in a hurry at the company I work for. To give an example, when I am still at a level to turn on and off the light with the raspberry pi, they want me to take the electrical data from the device and process it on the hmi screen. I would like to learn step by step and apply, but I am stuck in such a situation. :(